# remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied - Private gitlab instance tokens

Tags: authentication, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am running a job in a private gitlab instance `https:gitlab.example.com` but my pipeline always fail due to some tokens that I need to provide, I don't know which tokens I need to configure for my pipeline to work. Any help?

**Error:**

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab.example.com/project/front.git/'
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
stages:
  - test

test-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"'
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    - docker info
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
  tags:
    - test
```